# Follow dynamic hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, excel-2010

I have a worksheet with four columns. Column A has an ID number, B has description, C has location and D has a link to an image of the item.

I have a macro that asks the user for an ID# and searches column A. A message box displays the location of the tooling. I would like the hyperlink in Column D to open in a new window upon selecting the "Okay" button on the message box.

Here's what I have so far.

```
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
FindString = InputBox("Enter Tooling ID#")
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A") 
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True 'value found
            MsgBox "Tooling " & Rng & " is located at " & Rng.Offset(, 2).Value & "."

        Else
            MsgBox "Tooling not found" 'value not found
        End If
    End With
End If
```

Comment: This looks like it could be done with if, vlookup, and hyperlink worksheet functions, without any macros at all. eg. =if(not(iserr(vlookup(E1,A:C,3,false))),hyperlink(vlookup(E1,A:C,3,false),"Tooling is found at " &vlookup(E1,A:C,3,false)),"Tooling not found"), where e1 is where the user would enter the tooling ID#

Answer (score 0):

To follow a Hyperlink and open it in a new window (True):

```
    Range("A8").Hyperlinks(1).Follow (True)
```

It should open in the appropriate application.

[Hyperlink.Follow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839219.aspx)

If if is not configured to open in the appropriate application, then you might read the link-address from the cell and investigate using `Shell` to start, for example, Paint:

```
Shell "MSPaint ""F:\Documents and Settings\student\My Documents\My Pictures\blog1.png"""
```